# Should I use the input's onclick or the form's onsubmit event to validate form fields using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, forms

I have  a simple form with fields that I am trying to validate using JavaScript.  In the form I have an input type of submit.

For validation, should I call the validation function for onclick event on the input or onsubmit of the form? Is there any implication of choosing one over the other one?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`onsubmit` is triggered whenever the form is about to be submitted.
`onclick` is triggered when the specific button is clicked.

Forms can be submitted by hitting the <kbd>enter</kbd> key in any input field. This would not trigger the `onclick` of the submit button, but it would trigger the form submit event. As such, use `onsubmit`.

Comment: Thanks , your answer has cleared the doubt.I appreciate your feedback.

Comment: Enter _does_ trigger the onclick in for example chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/3A4Ha/

Answer (score 1):

Both **onclick** and **onsubmit** do the same thing. **No matter** you **press enter** on a text input element or **press submit button**, both are triggered. If you use both onclick and onsubmit events, they are both executed respectively. And if You have more than one submit buttons in the form, the first submit button's onclick method is executed. Tested on Internet Explorer, Firefox, Chrome and Opera.