# Javascript - Form still submits after error message

Tags: javascript, html, forms

Probably a little typo or something, but I have looked and looked, and I can't find it.  I have looked at numerous postings for the exact same thing, and I still can't figure it out.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
<script language="Javascript">

function validateForm()
{
  var x = document.addNewForm.ecrNumber.value;
  if (x==null || x=="")
  {
    alert("ECR Number must be filled out");
    document.addNewform.ecrNumber.focus();
    return false;
  }

  var y=document.addNewForm.origin.value;
  if (y==null || y=="")
  {
    alert("Originator Name must be filled out");
    document.addNewform.origin.focus();
    return false;
  }
  var des=document.addNewform.descript.value;
  if (des=null || des=="")
  {
    alert("Description must be filled out");
    document.addNewform.descript.focus();
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}



</script>
```

And the html

```
 <form name="addNewForm" action="index.php/ecr-form-to-database" onSubmit="return validateForm();" method="post">
 <table width="60%">
    <tr><td>ECR No.: </td><td><input type="textbox" id="ecrNumber" name="ecrNumber" /> </td> </tr>
    <tr><td>Originator Name: </td><td><input type="textbox" id="origin" name="origin" value="<?php print $empName;?>" / ></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Description:</td><td><textarea id="descript" name="descript"></textarea></td></tr>
    <tr><td> </td><td> </td></tr>
    <tr><td colspan="2" style="text-align:center"><input type="submit" value="Submit Form" /></td></tr>
    </table>
    </form>
```

Comment: `if (des=null || des=="")`

Comment: Open the console -> `Cannot read property 'ecrNumber' of undefined`, in other words, `document.addNewform` doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: Just to clarify: if your validation function to throws an error, the form will still submit by its default action (submission has not been prevented by the JS). The question here appears to be "where is my JS error?".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not all browsers store forms and ID's directly on the document, but as all your elements have ID's, why aren't you using that :

```
function validateForm() {
    var x   = document.getElementById('ecrNumber');
    var y   = document.getElementById('origin');
    var des = document.getElementById('descript');

    if ( ! x.value ) {
        alert("ECR Number must be filled out");
        x.focus();
        return false;
    }

    if ( ! y.value ) {
        alert("Originator Name must be filled out");
        y.focus();
        return false;
    }

    if ( ! des.value ) {
        alert("Description must be filled out");
        des.focus();
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/CbAFf/6/)

Comment: Got caught up in a quick meeting so I wasn't able to thank you earlier.  But Thanks, completely worked.  I should've thought to try it this way.  Not too advanced on javascript, more a software type that got turned into web dev for a new job.

Answer (score 0):

You have not called the function validateForm.

```
<input type="submit" onclick="return validateForm();" value="Submit Form" />
```

Comment: It's in the `<form>` tag: `onSubmit="return validateForm();"`

Comment: Actually it still won't work...  still submits.  any other ideas?  thanks for the quick response by the way.

Comment: @dougjore Yes, you should add this to submit event. W3Schools is correct.

Comment: Using `onsubmit` will also catch submissions by hitting the "enter" key (and other methods), rather than just the submit button. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6908187/form-onsubmit-versus-submit-button-onclick#6909770

Comment: @dougjore - you're doing it right, this answer is wrong, and it's lowercase -> `onsubmit`, not `onSubmit`

Comment: @adeneo How is the answer wrong when the OP said it worked for him? And besides, onclick is a perfectly legal event for the <input /> tag. Get your facts right mate.

Comment: Sure it is, but the onsubmit event on the form itself would be the proper event to bind a handler to when validating a form, which is exactly what the OP is doing.

Comment: @adeneo I appreciate you trying to help but what exactly do you mean by 'proper' event. It's one of the options I agree, but not the absolute right option.

Comment: @JeevanJose I agree with adeneo . If you hit enter in the form fields the onclick will not trigger and onsubmit is the right choice.

Comment: ^^^^ My point exactly. onclick on the submit button is the right choice if you're trying to figure out if someone clicked the button. If you're trying to figure out if someone submitted the form, it's the wrong choice, as there are many ways to submit a form, and when validating you almost never want the onclick event handler on the submit button. Also, the issue isn't that there is something wrong with the onsubmit event handler, it's exactly the right event handler, the issue is syntax errors in the code, and using the wrong case on the events etc, so the answer is misleading.

Comment: @adeneo and pvnarula; Guys I do agree that in theory that is the case. But modern browsers are capable of figuring this out. Check this fiddle out: http://jsfiddle.net/ZBzux/1/

Like you can see no matter whether you hit the return key with focus in the textbox or click the submit button, the function is fired nonetheless.